# Maintaining a set of smallest subsets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, subset

Here are the operations that I'd like to perform on a hypothetical collection data structure that holds sets as its elements:

1. Insert a set into the data structure, but: (1) if the new set is a superset of any of the existing sets, don't add it (2) if the new set is a subset of any existing sets, remove them.
2. Enumerate all the sets currently in the collection

All the sets in question are subsets of a known finite set, say {0..10^4}.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: what is "efficient" ? do you have any concrete limitations ?

Comment: What happens if you have a whole bunch of sets in the structure, then add a superset of all those sets to the structure?  Does it delete the old ones?

Comment: Well, I'm exploring a possible constraint solving technique. Roughly the idea is that constraint solvers try to learn new constraints during their search. The problem with this is that the constraint database gets very big and slow as a lot of constraints get added. Many constraints are redundant. A constraint is redundant if it is a superset of another constraint (roughly speaking). I'd like have a data structure that maintains only the smallest subsets. There's not a fixed limitation; just that faster is better as then the constraint solver will be able to handle bigger problems.

Comment: @templatetypedef: yes, exactly :) I forgot to mention that in the question; I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recent paper on this problem: http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36974.html

Briefly, you cannot do much better than quadratic time in the worst case; but there are some tricks to speed it up in practice.

Answer (score 1):

> All the sets in question are subsets of a known finite set, say {0..10^4}.

Let's call this N = 10^4. This is reasonably small, and this will prove useful. Let's say you have S sets.

'Logically' this means you have an N*S matrix.

You will already have a set of sets. There are S sets in this primary structure.

10^4 is sufficiently small that you could maintain a *secondary* data structure which stores, for each the N values, the list of *sets* that it is in. This structure is sort of like the transpose of the primary structure. This could be a vector of length N, allowing constant time lookup to find the list of sets that a particular value is in.

Now, when you add a new set, it will be possible to use this secondary structure to find which other sets each of its values are in. For example, we add a new set with values 2,5, 10

```
new_set = {2,5,10}
```

The secondary structure tells us which sets they are in:

```
 2 : {A,B,D}
 5 : {B,D}
10 : {B}
```

We can merge and sort these three lists to get `ABBBDD` which tells us not only which sets it overlaps with, but the size of the overlaps. Three nodes are shared with B, which means that our new set is a subset of, or equal to, B. We share 1 node with A, and two nodes with D. If it turns out that the total size of A is 1, then we now know that A is a subset of our new set.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating the sets in the collection is easy, O(n).  However, checking a new candidate for whether it's a subset of all the existing sets is going to be somewhat expensive.  There are well known algorithms for testing if one set is subset of another, so simple

```
for each subset s in S
    for each candidate set C
        test of C is a subset of s
        if it is, break
if never found, add C to S.
```

That's going to be something like O(n^2 lg n).  Does that count as "efficient"?

Comment: That's the brute force method. I was hoping for something more efficient ;)

Comment: I don't have time or space to try to write a proof right now, but I suspect O(n^2 lg n) is optimal. I don't think you can make the outer loops better than O(|S|*number of C candidates) and I don't think you can test for subset in less than O(lg n). I think a proof then follows by contradiction.

Comment: That argument is just showing that there is no obvious way to improve your algorithm. Why couldn't there be a completely different algorithm?

Comment: There appear to be better algorithms, in fact, with sub-quadratic time (see Falk Hüffner's answer or search for "An Old Sub-Quadratic Algorithm for Finding Extremal Sets").

Comment: Jules, when someone says "I suspect but I can't write a proof right now" that means "but I might be wrong."

Comment: I'm sorry if that offended you somehow, no offense intended. Generally I like when people give me interesting information (like the existence of a sub quadratic algorithm), *especially* if it challenges my previous guesses.

Comment: I's not that you offended me, it's that one must be precise.

Comment: Then we're all right: I never said that you said that you couldn't be wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a bloom filter for all of the stored sets. Generate a bloom filter for the set to be inserted. If you bitwise AND the filter for the set to be inserted (call this X) with another set's bloom filter, and get the value X back, then your set to be inserted MIGHT be a subset (possibly a false positive, you need to check the slow way at this point). Otherwise it is definitely not and you can try with another.

There are many adjustable parameters when building a bloom filter that allow you to make tradeoffs between space efficiency and probability of false positives.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Answer (score 0):

For space efficiency, you can use a bit set to represent each subset of the known finite set. There are also methods for representing sparse bit sets (see, e.g., [this Java sample](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/magercises/BitSet/index.html)), to gain further space savings.

The overall structure could be a set of bit sets. In Java, `BitSet` does not have a subset test method, but I don't think it would be too hard to extend `BitSet` to include an efficient subset test method. (This would avoid the obnoxious task of testing whether the candidate to be added is equal to its intersection with any of the existing subsets.)

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of tree structure.

Eg. Store the sorted existing sets in a Trie. At each node maintain a Flag if the path leading to that node is an existing set

1 To check if the given set is a superset of an already existing set:

> ```
> def issuperset(node, set[N], setc, N):
>     if node.is_set:
>         return True
>     for j = setc:N
>         if set[j] is a child of node:
>             if issuperset(node.child[set[j]], set, j+1, N):
>                 return True
>     return False
> ```

2  Remove all the supersets of a given set

> ```
> def remsuperset(node, set[N], setc, N):
>     if setc == N+1:
>         remove_all_sets_on_or_below_this_node(node)
>         return
>     for ch in node.child:
>         if ch< set[setc]:
>             remsuperset(node.child[ch], set, setc, N)
>         elif ch == set[setc]:
>             remsuperset(node.child[ch], set, setc+1, N)
> ```

3 For enumerating sets just traverse the tree and print path is is_set flag is True